# Question on Separated set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider two separated sets $A$ and $B$ of $R^k$. If $a $$\in $$A $ and $b $$\in $$B $ then

$p (t)=(1-t)a+tb$.

Now consider $C=p^{-1}(A) $ and $D=p^{-1}(B) $. 
Now prove that  $C $ and $D $ are separated in $R $. 
Is it even true. I mean the can have many values. And not necessarily all of the values are gonna lie in same set?? Am I missing something??Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are $p$ and $P$ the same?

Comment: Thanks for observing the mistake. Yes they are same

Answer (score 1):

If they were not separated in $\mathbb{R}$, there would be real sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ with $p(a_n)\in A$, $p(b_n)\in B$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-b_n|=0$.

But then we have that

\begin{align}
\lVert p(a_n)-p(b_n)\rVert&=
\left\lVert (1-a_n)\cdot a+a_n\cdot b - \big[(1-b_n)\cdot a+b_n\cdot b\big]\right\rVert\\
&=\left\lVert (b_n-a_n)\cdot a+(a_n-b_n)\cdot b\right\rVert.
\end{align}

Since the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is continuous this would imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert p(a_n)-p(b_n)\rVert=0$, which would contradict $A$ and $B$ being separated in $\mathbb{R}^k$. It follows that $C$ and $D$ must be separated in $\mathbb{R}$.